# How to Fix "There has been an error processing your request :: Specified invalid parent id (Magento_Backend::mgs)" in Admin Panel..?

Tags: magento2

I'm using Magento2,when i login on my website i got this message.

> There has been an error processing your request Specified invalid
>   parent id (Magento_Backend::mgs) Error log record number:
>   1307308720759

This website was working fine but last day i run a query and recompile and then this issue start coming up....

Below Error Log Detail

> {"0":"Specified invalid parent id (Magento_Backend::mgs)","1":"#0
>   /home/gervetus/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
>   Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder->getResult(Object(Magento\Backend\Model\Menu))\n#1
>   /home/gervetus/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder\Interceptor->___callParent('getResult',
>   Array)\n#2
>   /home/gervetus/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Backend\Model\Menu))\n#3
>   /home/gervetus/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Menu/Builder/Interceptor.php(26):
>   Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getResult',
>   Array, Array)\n#4
>   /home/gervetus/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Menu/Config.php(148):
>   Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder\Interceptor->getResult(Object(Magento\Backend\Model\Menu))\n#5
>   /home/gervetus/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Menu/Config.php(111):
>   Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Config->_initMenu()\n#6
>   /home/gervetus/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Url.php(361):
>   Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Config->getMenu()\n#7
>   /home/gervetus/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Url.php(321):
>   Magento\Backend\Model\Url->_getMenu()\n#8
>   /home/gervetus/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Url/Interceptor.php(102):
>   Magento\Backend\Model\Url->getStartupPageUrl()\n#9
>   /home/gervetus/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(276):
>   Magento\Backend\Model\Url\Interceptor->getStartupPageUrl()\n#10
>   /home/gervetus/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(208):
>   Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->_processUrlKeys()\n#11
>   /home/gervetus/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
>   Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#12
>   /home/gervetus/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch',
>   Array)\n#13
>   /home/gervetus/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143):
>   Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#14
>   /home/gervetus/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor),
>   Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#15
>   /home/gervetus/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#16
>   /home/gervetus/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Backend/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(26):
>   Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch',
>   Array, NULL)\n#17
>   /home/gervetus/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55):
>   Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#18
>   /home/gervetus/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#19
>   /home/gervetus/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch',
>   Array)\n#20
>   /home/gervetus/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#21
>   /home/gervetus/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch',
>   Array, Array)\n#22
>   /home/gervetus/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#23
>   /home/gervetus/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()\n#24
>   /home/gervetus/public_html/index.php(40):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))\n#25
>   {main}","url":"/admin/admin/index/index/key/6570ae1e6f609b1c1c0433e9e2307b5d7250e1e160091871b57a4326817cae2e/","script_name":"/index.php"}

Answer (score 2):

Just modify the menu file located under **/vendor/magento/module-cms/etc/adminthml/menu.xml**

```
<add id="Magento_Backend::mgs" title="Blocks" translate="title" module="Magento_Cms" sortOrder="30" parent="Magento_Backend::mgs" action="cms/block" resource="Magento_Cms::block"/>
```

Here's how it'll look

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Magento_Cms::cms_page" title="Pages" translate="title" module="Magento_Cms" sortOrder="0" parent="Magento_Backend::content_elements" action="cms/page" resource="Magento_Cms::page"/>
        <add id="Magento_Cms::cms_block" title="Blocks" translate="title" module="Magento_Cms" sortOrder="30" parent="Magento_Backend::content_elements" action="cms/block" resource="Magento_Cms::block"/>
        <add id="Magento_Backend::mgs" title="Blocks" translate="title" module="Magento_Cms" sortOrder="30" parent="Magento_Backend::mgs" action="cms/block" resource="Magento_Cms::block"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per error there is no any parent id name with mgs so it will throw error.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
<menu>
    <add id="Magento_Cms::cms_page" title="Pages" module="Magento_Cms" sortOrder="0" parent="Magento_Backend::content_elements" action="cms/page" resource="Magento_Cms::page"/>
    <add id="Magento_Cms::cms_block" title="Blocks" module="Magento_Cms" sortOrder="30" parent="Magento_Backend::content_elements" action="cms/block" resource="Magento_Cms::block"/>
</menu>
```

In the code above `parent="Magento_Backend::content_elements"` will display in content menu so give valid `id` to your menu then it will work.

For reference see this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126502/specifies-invalid-parent-id-magento-backendmgs)

Comment: could you please guide me where this file and what i edit...?

Comment: You need server access as may be you need to enable/disable any module. and by this you need to run upgrade script too. As your admin is not working then you must need server to remove cache if you think this issue is in cache related.

Comment: i already reset Cache but still same issue facing and i have SSH access and FTP access just guide me what i do to fix this issue..?